# Grid display problem in Tikz and Pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, grids

I'm having trouble displaying some of my grids. Here is an MWE to illustrate :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis}[
        grid=both,
        xmin=5e-2,                  xmax=3e1,
        ymin=0,                     ymax=100,
        width=12cm,                 height=8cm,
    ]
        \addplot coordinates{
            (22.4,100)(11.2,73.01)(1.2,39.12)(0.4,6.87)(0.08,1.53)
        };
    \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=2.5cm,y=2.5cm]
    \begin{axis}[
        x=2.5cm,y=2.5cm,
        axis lines=middle,
        grid=both,
        grid style={line width=.2pt, draw=gray!30},
        major grid style={line width=.4pt,draw=gray!70},
        minor tick num ={3},
        xmin=-3.2,
        xmax=3.2,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2.4,
        xtick={-3.0,-2.0,...,3.0},
        ytick={0.0,1.0,...,2.5},
        ]

        \clip(-3.2,-0.2) rectangle (3.2,2.4);
        \draw[samples=500,domain=-3.2:3.2]
            plot(\x,{abs((\x)-2.0*floor((\x)/2.0)-1.0)+3.0/4.0*abs(4.0*(\x)-2.0*floor(4.0*(\x)/2.0)-1.0)+9.0/16.0*abs(16.0*(\x)-2.0*floor(16.0*(\x)/2.0)-1.0)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the first figure, I don't have a vertical line for 2*10^1.

In the second figure, I don't have a horizontal line for 2.25. (By the way, do you know how to automatically add the "0" on the axis with the option `axis lines=middle` ?)

On the other hand, if, for example, I write for the first figure: `xmax=4e1`. I do have a vertical line for 2*10^1.

[image]

Do you know what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your subquestions:

1. The first point is probably some numerical issue. The manual also mentions that using `xtickten` is faster, and it is probably more accurate. And indeed `xtickten={-2,...,2},` makes the vertical grid line appear.
2. The second issue is an input problem, at least it seems a little bit unfortunate to me to use `{0.0,1.0,...,2.5},`, which starts with a step length of 1 but the upper bound is not consistent with that (but I am not saying it is wrong). `ytick={0,1,...,3},` fixes this problem.
3. Finally, you get the `0` with the `hide obscured x    ticks=false` key.

And an off-topic issue: you say (even twice)
    `x=2.5cm,y=2.5cm,` but this makes the plot too wide for your
    document. I changed this to `width=\textwidth,axis equal,`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmode=log,xtickten={-2,...,2},
        grid=both,
        xmin=5e-2,                  xmax=3e1,
        ymin=0,                     ymax=100,
        width=12cm,                 height=8cm,
    ]
        \addplot coordinates{
            (22.4,100)(11.2,73.01)(1.2,39.12)(0.4,6.87)(0.08,1.53)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45]
    \begin{axis}[hide obscured x ticks=false,width=\textwidth,
        axis equal,
        axis lines=middle,
        grid=both,
        grid style={line width=.2pt, draw=gray!30},
        major grid style={line width=.4pt,draw=gray!70},
        minor tick num ={3},
        xmin=-3.2,
        xmax=3.2,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2.4,
        xtick={-3,-2,...,3},
        ytick={0,1,...,3},
        ]

        \clip(-3.2,-0.2) rectangle (3.2,2.4);
        \draw[samples=500,domain=-3.2:3.2]
            plot(\x,{abs((\x)-2.0*floor((\x)/2.0)-1.0)+3.0/4.0*abs(4.0*(\x)-2.0*floor(4.0*(\x)/2.0)-1.0)+9.0/16.0*abs(16.0*(\x)-2.0*floor(16.0*(\x)/2.0)-1.0)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: In addition to the off-topic suggestions made by Zarko for my second plot, one can improve the second plot further by choosing an appropriate number of samples that takes into account the `floor` function.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>={Straight Barb[angle=60:2 3]}]
    \begin{axis}[hide obscured x ticks=false,width=\textwidth,
        axis equal image,
        axis lines=middle,
        grid=both,
        grid style={line width=.2pt, draw=gray!30},
        major grid style={line width=.4pt,draw=gray!70},
        minor tick num =3,
        xmin=-3.2,
        xmax=3.2,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2.4,
        xtick={-3,-2,...,3},
        ytick={-1,...,3},
        ]
        \addplot[samples=64*3+1,domain=-3.2:3.2]
        {abs(x-2.0*floor(x/2.0)-1.0)+3.0/4.0*abs(4.0*x-2.0*floor(4.0*x/2.0)-1.0)+9.0/16.0*abs(16.0*x-2.0*floor(16.0*x/2.0)-1.0)};       
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But all of this is off-topic, the subquestions are answered in the upper part, i.e. my original answer.

Comment: +1: I use pgfplots for many years now and yet I find two new options in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

A small variation of the @Schrödinger's cat suggestion for the second diagram:

- grid is limited with `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax`
- added is line for y=2.25
- used is macro `\addplot`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>={Straight Barb[angle=60:2 3]}]
\begin{axis}[
    width=\textwidth,
    axis equal image,       % <---
    axis lines=middle,
    axis on top, 
    grid=both,
    grid style={thin, draw=gray!30},
    major grid style={draw=gray!70},
    minor tick num ={3},
    xmin=-3.3,  xmax=3.3,   % <---
    ymin=-0.4,  ymax=2.4,   % <---
    xtick={-3,-2,...,3},
    hide obscured x ticks=false,
    ytick={-1,0,1,2,3},     % <---
    tick label style={font=\small, inner sep=2pt, fill=white}
            ]
\addplot [samples=500,domain=-3.2:3.2] % <---
    {abs(x-2*floor(x/2)-1.0) + 3.0/4.0*abs(4*x-2*floor(4.0*x/2)-1.0) + 9/16*abs(16*(x)-2*floor(16*x/2)-1)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]